# Override activity in workflow?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have a complicated workflow for sending marketing emails to customers.  There's something like twenty activities that decide who gets what kind of email.

95% of my activities are defined in a binary activity library.  I assembled my main activity in visual studio.

For certain types of customer I want to have the activity in (say) step 25a behave differently than what I defined when I built it.  We could load the activity from xaml hosted in a database.

One option is to clone the entire workflow for those customers, but that is a lot of code duplication.

Is it possible to override whatever the runtime uses to locate and marshal activities so that if my customer is left handed, one activity in the workflow is substituted instead of what I defined in the IDE?

I'm thinking of how you can override the ViewEngine in mvc to dynamically load ipad views or whatever.  Is there something similar for loading activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news... I have built exactly what you need for this in Microsoft.Activities.  For details see [WF4 How To Invoke a Child Workflow as XAML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/03/29/wf4-how-to-invoke-a-child-workflow-as-xaml.aspx) and just yesterday I added support for tracking child workflows see [Tracking Child Workflow with InvokeWorkflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/26/tracking-child-workflow-with-invokeworkflow.aspx)

Comment: Hey Ron, I've been looking at your videos all week!  I'll check it out.  WF is such a "snap together lego solution" that I was hoping there was an easy way to automagically swap steps without having to recompile the app.  We do a lot of custom rules per customer and we are hoping that WF can save us from redeploying for each case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace the activity in the workflow itself if it is compiled into the assembly. There are several options you can use though:

- Use a dynamically loaded activity using the ActivityXamlServices.Load() and as XAML is just XML change the XAML before laoding it.
- Use a wrapper activity in your workflow that only loads the actual activity at runtime and uses the WorkflowInvoker to execute it.
- Separate the intent from the implementation by using an activity and an extension. The activity only grabs all inputs and the extension and calls a function on it. At runtime you can vary the actual implementation of the workflow extension depending on your needs.